# differentiate cos x inside integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} e^x (\sin x+\cos x)\mathrm dx$$
$$\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} e^x(\sin x+\frac{d}{dx} \sin x)\mathrm dx$$

But, If I differentiate $\cos x$ than, I get $-\sin x$. But, why there's no negative above? I took the above equation from my book.

Comment: To be clear: Are you asking why the first expression is equal to the second?

Comment: If you were given the second expression, would you be able to convert it into first?

Comment: @Blue No! I got my answer below. I couldn't accept it few moments. That's why I didn't..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **not** differentiating $\cos x$ under the integral sign, you are simply using the equality

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \cos x$$

to replace the right-hand side with the left-hand side.

Comment: But, $\frac{d}{dx}$ used for differentiation....

Comment: Yes, but you are taking the derivative of $\sin$, not of $\cos$. That's why there is no minus sign

Comment: So, what happened to [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209037/differentiate-inside-integration)?

Comment: It's the same thing: $\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{1}{z}) = -\frac{1}{z^2}$ (though I don't know what happened with the integration boundaries there?)

Comment: What I am trying to say is: there is a thing called "differentiating under the integral", where under some assumptions you can swap integrals and derivatives. It is a bit messy, but it is **not** what is happening here. Here you just have two things which are **equal**, so you can replace one with the other in any expression.

Comment: Ohh! Now I understood what you are talking

Comment: @Istiak: You confusion seems to be the same in the two questions -- you're differentiating in the wrong direction. It looks like you're seeing "$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x$" in the second integral and you think it means "... and the derivative of the thing above is $\sin x$" -- which is completely wrong, it means "... then add whatever the derivative of $\sin x$ is".

Answer (score 1):

What the authors were doing was that they were taking advantage of the fact that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin{x}=\cos{x}$ and substituted one for the other in order to make it clear that the reverse product rule should be used. Look closely at $\int e^{x}(\sin{x}+\cos{x}) dx$. It can be rewritten as $\int (e^{x}\sin{x}+e^{x}\cos{x}) dx$, or $\int (\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{x})\sin{x}+e^{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin{x})) dx $. If you know some of the elementary properties of derivatives, you'll know that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{x})\sin{x}+e^{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin{x})$ is just $\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{x}\sin{x})$. So in the end, you can just cancel out the integral and the derivative (since they are kinda like inverse operations) and rewrite the integral as just $e^{x}\sin{x}$ evaluated from $0$ to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, which is just $e^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$.